# MCA: Data CACHE Level-0 Read Error

Tags: 14.04, debian

I often encounter "Processor contect corrupt" error. And after that operating system restarts itself in 30 seconds. The full mscelog log is below:

```
mcelog: Unsupported new Family 6 Model 3c CPU: only decoding architectural erro$
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
MCE 0
CPU 3 BANK 1
MISC 86 ADDR 1eabe1680
TIME 1407525231 Fri Aug  8 15:13:51 2014
MCG status:
MCi status:
Corrected error
MCi_MISC register valid
MCi_ADDR register valid
MCA: Data CACHE Level-0 Read Error
STATUS 8c00004000000114 MCGSTATUS 0
MCGCAP c09 APICID 6 SOCKETID 0
CPUID Vendor Intel Family 6 Model 60
```

I tried to test memory using memtest86+. I didn't encounter any error.

> CPUInfo

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 60
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4440 CPU @ 3.10GHz
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x7
cpu MHz         : 800.000
cache size      : 6144 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
bogomips        : 6186.62
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

If you want to learn more information about the machine, I can add.

Answer (score 0):

Every other forum says that this is almost always a hardware error, (i.e. I'm sorry man.) Though one thing I read said that occasionally it is because a machine runs too hot. I've had some trouble with that myself in the last few ubuntu releases, though I've never had my proc throw errors at me.

if your machine has been running hot try,

```
cd /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/
for interrupt in $(ls /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/)
do
echo $interrupt
cat ./$interrupt
done
```

if one of these numbers is exceptionally high,

```
$ sudo su
# echo disable > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/<insert your offending interrupt here>
```

I hope it's just the heat and that this is your solution, otherwise, it looks like a physical malfunction of the processor.